# How to pass input to EventRule for a StepFunction Target in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, pipeline, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

```
Parameters:
Bucket:
  Default: bucket_1
  Type: String
  AllowedValues:
   - bucket_1
   - bucket_2

Resources:
StepFunction:
  Type: 'AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine'
  Properties:
   DefinitionString: |-
    {
        ...
    }
   RoleArn: ...
   StateMachineName: ...

EventRule:
  Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
  Properties:
      ScheduleExpression: cron(...)
      Targets:
        - RoleArn: ...
          Arn: !Ref StepFunction
          Id: "ScheduleStepFunction"
          InputTransformer:
            InputPathsMap:
              Bucket: !Ref Bucket
            InputTemplate: "{\"Bucket\": <Bucket>}"
```

I am trying to pass input parameter named `Bucket`, defined as a parameter in the CloudFormation Template itself, to a StepFunction Target of the Event Rule.

**`I get this error: InputPath for target ScheduleStepFunction is invalid.`**

**`Note: The optional parameter 'InputPath' has not been provided also.`**

Answer (score 1):

```
Targets:
        - RoleArn: ...
          Arn: !Ref StepFunction
          Id: "ScheduleStepFunction"
          InputTransformer:
            InputPathsMap:
              Bucket: !Ref Bucket
            InputTemplate: "{\"Bucket\": <Bucket>}"
```

It seems like your **Targets** have some issue because there is no **Input** is mention in your target as suggested by the Amazon eventRule documentation. Go to the provided link to use Input in target as suggested by AWS UserGuide.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html